# git diff name only A M and D meaning

Tags: git, git-diff

I did

```
git diff --name-only commit1 commit2
```

and I get a list

```
A file1
M file2
D file3
```

What does the A, M, and D stand for?   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A**dded, **m**odified, and **d**eleted.